# How to get file data from its uri in android

Tags: android

How to get file data from its uri in android.We tried following code but its giving filenot found exception.
uri2 = intent.getData();

```
        uri = uri2.toString();
        File objFile = new File(uri);
        try {
            InputStream data = new FileInputStream(objFile);
            Log.d("data", data+"");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please do help.
Thanks,
AA.

Comment: What does your `uri2` contains ? Check if the file exists on that location or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file path with the following piece of code :

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

call the above function as follows :

```
String myFilePath = getPath(uri);
File objFile = new File(myFilePath);
```